# How to handle null from a text file in Mysql if the data type is Char(1)?

Tags: mysql, csv, null

This is my first time trying Mysql. I created a table using the following command.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `COMPANY`.`EMPLOYEE` (
  `Fname` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `Minit` CHAR NULL,
  `Lname` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `Ssn` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  `Bdate` DATE NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Sex` CHAR NULL,
  `Salary` DECIMAL(10,2),
  `Super_ssn` CHAR(9) NULL,
  `Dno` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ssn`));
```

And I was trying to fill the table using the command below:

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\EMPLOYEE.txt' 
INTO TABLE employee
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(Fname,Minit,Lname,Ssn,@var2,Address,Sex,Salary,Super_ssn,Dno)
SET Bdate=str_to_date(@var2,'%d-%b-%Y');
```

And this is my text file

```
'James', 'E', 'Borg', '888665555', '10-NOV-1927', '450 Stone,Houston,TX', 'M', 55000, null, 1
'Franklin',null, 'Wong', '333445555', '08-DEC-1945', '638 Voss,Houston,TX', 'M', 40000, '888665555', 5
```

I am getting an error saying:
**Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'Minit' at row 2**
How do I solve this?

Comment: If this is Windows, the lines should be terminated by `'\r\n'`

Comment: Also keep in mind 'null' should be encoded `\N` but I agree with Barmar, the problem is probably your line terminator.

Comment: The error is about the `Minit` column, which has nothing to do with the null.

Comment: I accidentally copied the wrong line from the text file. The question is now updated. The Mint column in the second row should have a null value. How to I handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you used `optionally` in the `enclosed by` setting. If the enclosing character is required, it will treat `null` with no quotes around it as a `NULL` value. Otherwise, it interprets it as the literal string `"null"`, and requires you to use `\N` to specify a null value.

You could use an intermediate variable to translate it yourself.

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\EMPLOYEE.txt' 
INTO TABLE employee
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(Fname,@Minit,Lname,Ssn,@var2,Address,Sex,Salary,Super_ssn,Dno)
SET Bdate=str_to_date(@var2,'%d-%b-%Y'), Minit = NULLIF(@Minit, 'null')
```